# Create a menu inside a Class

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-menu

I have been resisting posting this question but have finally decided to put my pride in my pocket and admit that I cannot get the menu creation section of my program to work. I still do not seem to have been able to fully grasp the workings of Classes.
The program that I have written is basically a Cashbook keeping track of cash receipts and expenses and analysing them to various accounts. This all works fine. Then I also added a second window to add analysis items. This also works fine. However, finally I have tried to add a menu but cannot get it to work. When I run the program it does not throw out any errors but no menu ('File/Exit') appears. Can someone please look at the following (Menu_ex) code and tell me where it fails? Thank you in anticipation.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
import sqlite3
import datetime as dt
import time
from tkinter import messagebox as msgbox
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from prettytable import MSWORD_FRIENDLY
import subprocess, sys

class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.geometry('450x200')
        self.title('Add a new Analysis Item')


        def Item_sel(): 
            """ Set the value of the selected Radio buttons"""

            global item_choice
            global Item_Cat

            item_choice=Item_radio_var.get()

            
            if item_choice==1:


                Item_Analyse.config(state='normal')
                print('Item_radio_var = ' + str(item_choice))
                Item_Cat='IncCat'
                print('The item selected is ' + Item_Cat)
                Item_Analyse.focus()
                
            elif item_choice==2:
                #Item_Analyse.delete(0,tk.END)
                Item_Analyse.config(state='normal')
                print('Item_radio_var = ' + str(item_choice))
                Item_Cat='ExpCat'
                print('The item selected is ' + Item_Cat)
                Item_Analyse.focus()

class Menu_ex():

    def __init__(self,parent):    
        super().__init__(parent)

        #self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        menubar=Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu=Menu(menubar)
        fileMenu.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File',menu=fileMenu)

    def onExit(self):

        self.quit()

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):    
        super().__init__()
        
        

        global format_date
        date = dt.datetime.now()
        format_date=f"{date:%Y-%m-%d}"
        print(format_date)
        self.title('My Nedbank Credit Card')
        self.geometry('1130x450')
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(width=False,height=False)
     

        """Create a Frame inside a Window to contain widgets"""

        frame1 = ttk.Frame(self)
        frame1.grid(column=0,row=0, pady=5, sticky='news')

        """Create widgets in Frame1"""

        l_Sub = tk.Label(frame1,text='Nedbank Credit Card', fg='blue')
        l_Sub.config(font=('Courier Bold', 16))
        l_Sub.place(relx=.05,rely=.5)
        l_Sub.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10,sticky='news',columnspan=4)

        l_SubHead = tk.Label(frame1,text='Enter transaction data', fg='blue')
        l_SubHead.config(font=('Courier Bold', 12))
        l_SubHead.place(relx=.05,rely=.5)
        l_SubHead.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10,sticky='news',columnspan=4)

def open_window(self):
        window = Window(self)
        window.grab_set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainWindow()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you using both grid and place layout managers within the same code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that you weren't actually creating an instance of your Menu class so it would never be displayed

Below code displays the menu and fixes the exit button

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu
#from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
import sqlite3
import datetime as dt
import time
from tkinter import messagebox as msgbox
#from prettytable import PrettyTable
#from prettytable import MSWORD_FRIENDLY
import subprocess, sys

class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.geometry('450x200')
        self.title('Add a new Analysis Item')


        def Item_sel(): 
            """ Set the value of the selected Radio buttons"""

            global item_choice
            global Item_Cat

            item_choice=Item_radio_var.get()

            
            if item_choice==1:


                Item_Analyse.config(state='normal')
                print('Item_radio_var = ' + str(item_choice))
                Item_Cat='IncCat'
                print('The item selected is ' + Item_Cat)
                Item_Analyse.focus()
                
            elif item_choice==2:
                #Item_Analyse.delete(0,tk.END)
                Item_Analyse.config(state='normal')
                print('Item_radio_var = ' + str(item_choice))
                Item_Cat='ExpCat'
                print('The item selected is ' + Item_Cat)
                Item_Analyse.focus()

class Menu_ex():

    def __init__(self,parent):    
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.menubar=Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=self.menubar)

        fileMenu=Menu(self.menubar)
        fileMenu.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.onExit)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label='File',menu=fileMenu)

    def onExit(self):

        self.parent.destroy()

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):    
        super().__init__()
        
        

        global format_date
        date = dt.datetime.now()
        format_date=f"{date:%Y-%m-%d}"
        print(format_date)
        self.title('My Nedbank Credit Card')
        self.geometry('1130x450')
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(width=False,height=False)
        self.menu = Menu_ex(self)
     

        """Create a Frame inside a Window to contain widgets"""

        frame1 = ttk.Frame(self)
        frame1.grid(column=0,row=0, pady=5, sticky='news')

        """Create widgets in Frame1"""

        l_Sub = tk.Label(frame1,text='Nedbank Credit Card', fg='blue')
        l_Sub.config(font=('Courier Bold', 16))
        l_Sub.place(relx=.05,rely=.5)
        l_Sub.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10,sticky='news',columnspan=4)

        l_SubHead = tk.Label(frame1,text='Enter transaction data', fg='blue')
        l_SubHead.config(font=('Courier Bold', 12))
        l_SubHead.place(relx=.05,rely=.5)
        l_SubHead.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10,sticky='news',columnspan=4)

def open_window(self):
        window = Window(self)
        window.grab_set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainWindow()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Bryan and Scotty3785 for your replies. Scotty3785, I don't know why I used .place as well as .grid. I have removed them with no adverse effects to my program so I will consider that as a bonus something learnt.

Comment: Bryan, your reply as usual is brilliant.  I am however, after I modified my program still getting some errors.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bushbug/TKinterFiles/NedCard.py", line 633, in <module>
    app = MainWindow()
  File "/home/bushbug/TKinterFiles/NedCard.py", line 235, in __init__
    self.menu = Menu_ex(self)
  File "/home/bushbug/TKinterFiles/NedCard.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.initUI()
  File "/home/bushbug/TKinterFiles/NedCard.py", line 210, in initUI
    self.menubar=Menu(self.parent)
NameError: name 'Menu' is not defined. Your comment please.

Comment: Bryan would it make sense for me to post the complete program? About 635 lines.

Comment: Bryan, just to be sure, the code you sent me works perfectly if I run it on its own but when I incorporate it in my program it produces the above errors. Obviously I have not given you enough information?

Comment: @FrankAldridge The "Menu  is not defined" error sounds like it is related to how you are importing tkinter. If you use `from tkinter import Menu` it will allow you to use the menu widget. `from tkinter import *` will import all the tkinter objects but is bad practice. Common method seems to be to do `import tkinter as tk` and then in your code do something like `self.menubar = tk.Menu(self.parent)` instead.

Comment: @FrankAldridge This might be something you want to post in a new question however. If this code works, accept the answer and ask a new question.